# Python DeDuplicate Sort columns and transform to a row

Tags: python, pandas

Given Data

```
Order_1 | Order_2 | Order_3
-----------------------
Bread    Egg        Key
Egg      Pen        Tea
         Pen        Book
         Key        Bag
```

Needs to be transformed as

```
Order_1,    Egg,    Bread       
Order_2,    Egg,    Key,    Pen 
Order_3,    Bag,    Book,   Key,    Tea
```

The Header became the index. Each Columns is sorted and De Duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicates and sort columns with this loop:

```
for c in df.columns:
    vals = sorted(df[c].dropna().unique())
    df[c] = vals + [np.nan for x in range(len(df) - len(vals))]
```

Then just transpose the DataFrame:

```
df = df.T
```